# Micronaut Hibernate JPA Error - Error loading BeanIntrospection for type

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to connect and save data in Postgresql database using micronaut(v3.9.4) hibernate jpa. But application is failing at runtime with below exceptions:

```
Error loading BeanIntrospection for type [class com.domain.repo.SearchMetadata]: Could not initialize class
 com.domain.repo.$SearchMetadata$Introspection | Root Cause : io.micronaut.core.beans.exceptions.IntrospectionException: Error loading
 BeanIntrospection for type [class com.domain.repo.SearchMetadata]: Could not initialize class com.domain.repo.$SearchMetadata$Introspection\r\n\tat
 io.micronaut.core.beans.DefaultBeanIntrospector.findIntrospection(DefaultBeanIntrospector.java:104)\r\n\tat
 io.micronaut.validation.validator.DefaultValidator.getBeanIntrospection(DefaultValidator.java:685)\r\n\tat
 io.micronaut.validation.validator.DefaultValidator.validate(DefaultValidator.java:129)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:116)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:214)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:100)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)\r\n\tat
 org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)\r\n\tat
 java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3303)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2438)\r\n\tat 
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)\r\n\tat
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)\r\n\tat 
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)\r\n\tat 
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\r\n\tat io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:459)\r\n\tat 
io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:858)\r\n\tat io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.commit(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:825)\r\n\tat 
io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.execute(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:154)\r\n\tat 
io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.execute(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:144)\r\n\tat 
io.micronaut.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalInterceptor.java:147)\r\n\tat 
io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)\r\n\tat
```

**Here is my datasource configuration:**

```
#Datasource properties
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:8080/comdevdb?currentSchema=comschema_dev
    username: ****
    password: ****
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

**Here is JPA configuration:**

```
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'com.domain.repo'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
```

**POM.xml dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**POM.xml under annotationProcessorPaths:**

```
<path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
                            <version>3.9.4</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-data-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>3.9.4</version>
                        </path>
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Introspected
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "search_metadata")
public class SearchMetadata {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "company_number", nullable = false)
    private String companyNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "company_search_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @Column(name = "sic_description")
    private String sicDescription;

    @Column(name = "internal_client")
    private Boolean internalClient;

    @Column(name = "section_29_client")
    private Boolean section29RegisteredClient;

    public SearchMetadata(String companyNumber, LocalDateTime timestamp, String sicDescription, Boolean internalClient, Boolean section29Client) {
        this.companyNumber = companyNumber;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.sicDescription = sicDescription;
        this.internalClient = internalClient;
        this.section29RegisteredClient = section29Client;
    }

    public SearchMetadata() {

    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
import com.domain.repo.SearchMetadata;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface SearchMetaDataRepo {
    Optional<SearchMetadata> findById(long id);

    SearchMetadata save(@NotBlank String companyName,
                               @NotBlank LocalDateTime timestamp,
                               String sicDescription,
                               Boolean internalClient,
                               Boolean section29Client);

}
```

**Implementation class:**

```
import com.domain.repo.SearchMetadata;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Optional;

@Singleton
public class SearchMetaDataRepoImpl implements SearchMetaDataRepo {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public SearchMetaDataRepoImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }


    @Override
    public Optional<SearchMetadata> findById(long id) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public SearchMetadata save(@NotBlank String companyNumber,
                                      @NotBlank LocalDateTime timestamp,
                                      String sicDescription,
                                      Boolean internalClient,
                                      Boolean section29Client) {
        SearchMetadata searchMetadata = new SearchMetadata(companyNumber,
                timestamp,
                sicDescription,
                internalClient,
                section29Client);

        entityManager.persist(searchMetadata);
        return SearchMetadata;
    }
}
```

**In addition calling overridden save method from one of Service class.**

**Table is already created in postgresql db instance:**

```
CREATE TABLE search_metadata (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    company_number VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    company_search_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    sic_description VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    internal_client BOOLEAN NULL,
    section_29_client BOOLEAN NULL
);
CREATE INDEX idx_company_number_search_date ON search_metadata USING BTREE (company_number, company_search_date);
```

I followed following micronaut official documentations:
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-jpa-hibernate-maven-java.html

Played around JPA and datasource configuration and various micronaut dependencies. Nothing worked!

**When I set logging at TRACE, I noticed:**
Entity class is scanned properly.
Postgres dialect is set: "message":"HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect"}

Any help in resolving this issue will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add Micronaut version amd other relevant version info to your question, and please add linebreaks to your stacktrace. It is at least 20 lines with 80 chars per line.

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks. Question details updated. Micronaut version is 3.9.4. Line breaks applied to stacktraces.

Comment: Personally, I find the guide you followed a little bit cumbersome. You could have used `io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository` and avoided having `SearchMetaDataRepoImpl`. Couldn't find any official guide for this, closest is https://medium.com/swlh/a-guide-to-building-a-micronaut-application-with-micronaut-data-support-e578aeea5dd6. Micronaut doc for that: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/

Comment: BTW: I have a Github repo you can have a look at. Micronaut 4.0.1 and Kotlin, but you'll get the idea: https://github.com/roar-skinderviken/postgres-testcontainer-demo

Comment: Hi again. I created a new app from https://micronaut.io/launch, added your code and some tests, fixed compile error on last line in `SearchMetaDataRepoImpl`, but was not able to recreate the error. Hence I believe the error is related to some other parts of the POM that is not shown in your question. BR

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks for your reply. I tried medium.com guide which you provided in above comment but encountering a different run time exception now. Sadly lil to no help available over the internet. Micronaut still not that mature and lacks wider community support.

io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again\r\n\tat io.micronaut.data.runtime.operations.DefaultRepositoryOperationsRegistry.provide

Comment: OK, are you able to build & run the repo I linked to? BR

Comment: Actually. I followed medium.com guide which you shared and after that tried by creating a new project using micronaut launch and it worked. Later I discovered in original project I had scope missing in a few dependencies. After correcting , application started working. Thanks again @RoarS.